# How do you DELETE with a JOIN and no ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query yields the list of records I want to delete ...

```
SELECT *
FROM `orderitems` as oi
LEFT JOIN `orders` as o
    ON (o.`orderid` = oi.`orderid`)
WHERE o.`date` = '2012-10-05'
  AND o.`status` = 'init';
```

Unfortunately, the tables were designed without an `id` field.
I've looked at other deletes with joins, but all use `id` fields.
And this doesn't work:

```
DELETE
FROM `orderitems` as oi
LEFT JOIN `orders` as o
    ON (o.`orderid` = oi.`orderid`)
WHERE o.`date` = '2012-10-05'
  AND o.`status` = 'init';
```

How does one `DELETE` the above set with a single MySQL query? (No PHP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
DELETE oi -- add the alias here
FROM `orderitems` as oi
LEFT JOIN `orders` as o
    ON (o.`orderid` = oi.`orderid`)
WHERE o.`date` = '2012-10-05'
  AND o.`status` = 'init';
```

or by using subquery

```
DELETE FROM `orderitems`
WHERE `orderid` IN
(
   SELECT o.`orderid`
   FROM `orders` as o
   WHERE o.`date` = '2012-10-05'  AND o.`status` = 'init'
)
```

Comment: Awesome! Learn something every day :)

Comment: yes, the first did... i feel dumb for not thinking of the subquery, it could be even more simplified, as the subquery doesn't need `orderitems` at all i think ...

Comment: great! :D oh yes, `orderitems` is not needed.

Comment: DELETE FROM `orderitems`
WHERE `orderid` IN
( SELECT `orderid`
 FROM `orders`
 WHERE `date` = '2012-10-05'
   AND `status` = 'init');